# How to temporarily grant a role to a User in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have function A() and function B(). A() is authorised only for ROLE_A whilst B() can be run by anyone.

However, B() itself needs to run A(). But this gives me an access denied exception when running as a non ROLE_A user.

That's the beat way to go about getting this to work? I thought of wrapping the A() call in B() with a call to add and remove ROLE_A but I don't want to pollute the method, and I don't know if this is kosher anyway.

Another idea I was tinkering with was to annotate B() with some sort of advice that can add the role automatically without polluting the function. Again, I don't know if this is kosher.

Any advice from those who have come across the same design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use case is quite weird. In my opinion you should *not* try to add/remove roles on the fly.

What you could do is to create a `C` private method that contains the code needed for `A` and `B` and then just call the `C` method from `A` and `B` which will be secured as they need to be !

Comment: Hm... Good point. I'll try to see if I can restructure it that way.

Comment: Thanks. This worked great (and makes much more sense than my original approach).